# How to avoid the processing, if an unnecessary key is pressed (include or exclude user-defined, pre-defined keyss) in PyQt5?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

How to avoid the processing, if an unnecessary key is pressed?  For Example, In my code, I use <kbd>Right Arrow</kbd> and <kbd>Left Arrow</kbd>key in keyPressEvent to move from one label to another label. and  I assign keys  <kbd>F5</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+ <kbd>A</kbd> and <kbd>ctrl+alt+p</kbd>  as shortcuts for labels. By default to print the First label **"Accounts"** is selected. Now if I press any key (like **u,v,a,alt,ctrl** etc), I get a result **"Accounts is selected"** as much as time, I pressed anyother keys. If I press <kbd>F5</kbd>, Label Manufacture is selected/print, But now I press any key then I get a print message "**Manufacture is selected**"

**My intention** is, If I press **right, left arrow keys or assigned Qkeysequence keys**, then only  I got a response(print selected Item), If I press any other keys, Avoid  processing and I don't want to display anything. **(Here, QKeySequence keys is a dynamic ones, not constant, it will differ form user to user)**

```
import sys

from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
  
class Dynamic_Widgets(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super(). __init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("Dynamic Widget")
        self.vbox1 = QVBoxLayout()
        self.vbox2 = QVBoxLayout()
        self.hbox = QHBoxLayout()
        self.hbox.addLayout(self.vbox1),self.hbox.addLayout(self.vbox2)
        self.hbox.addSpacing(5),self.setLayout(self.hbox)

        self.lbl_1 = QLabel("Accounts")
        self.lbl_2 = QLabel("Inventory")
        self.lbl_3 = QLabel("Manufacture")

        self.lbl_1_sc = QLabel("Alt+A")
        self.lbl_2_sc = QLabel("alt+ctrl+P")
        self.lbl_3_sc = QLabel("F5")

        self.store_sc = {}
        self.item_list = []
        self.item_list_sc = []

        self.vbox1.addWidget(self.lbl_1)
        self.vbox1.addWidget(self.lbl_2)
        self.vbox1.addWidget(self.lbl_3)
        self.item_list.append(self.lbl_1.text())
        self.item_list.append(self.lbl_2.text())
        self.item_list.append(self.lbl_3.text())

        self.vbox2.addWidget(self.lbl_1_sc)
        self.vbox2.addWidget(self.lbl_2_sc)
        self.vbox2.addWidget(self.lbl_3_sc)

        self.item_list_sc.append(self.lbl_1_sc.text())
        self.item_list_sc.append(self.lbl_2_sc.text())
        self.item_list_sc.append(self.lbl_3_sc.text())

        self.active_part = 1
        self.first_option = 0
        self.first_option_result = ""
        self.first_option_result = self.item_list[self.first_option]
        self.func_final_result()

        for count,item in enumerate(self.item_list):
            self.store_sc[count] = QShortcut(QKeySequence(f'{(self.item_list_sc[count])}'),self)
            self.store_sc[count].activated.connect(self.result)

    def result(self):
        shortcut = self.sender()
        sc_key = QKeySequence(shortcut.key()).toString()
        sc_key_index = self.item_list_sc.index(sc_key)
        self.first_option = sc_key_index
        self.first_option_result = self.item_list[sc_key_index]
        self.func_final_result()

    def keyPressEvent(self, event):
        if self.active_part == 1:
            if (event.key() == Qt.Key_Return or event.key() == Qt.Key_Enter) and self.first_option == 0:
                self.first_option = 0
            if event.key() == Qt.Key_Right and  self.first_option < len(self.item_list)-1:
                self.first_option = self.first_option + 1
            if event.key() == Qt.Key_Left and self.first_option > 0:
                self.first_option = self.first_option - 1
            if self.first_option != -1:
                self.first_option_result = self.item_list[self.first_option]
                self.func_final_result()

    def func_final_result(self):
        print(self.first_option_result, "is selected")

def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Dynamic_Widgets()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: `if event.key() in (Qt.Key_Return, Qt.Key_Enter, Qt.Key_Left, Qt.Key_Right):` then do the processing, or, alternatively, `if event.key() not in (...): return`

Comment: @musicamante    How to include or exclude Qkeysequence keys, Which is user-defined .

Comment: Why do you need that? The QShortcut is not processed in the `keyPressEvent` and will be triggered anyway. Besides, be aware that you should *not* compare the shortcut with the string representation used for its creation, as it might throw an exception if the string doesn't use capitalized text for modifiers.

Comment: Also, what is the point of the first `if ... and self.first_option == 0:` if then you set `self.first_option` to 0 *again*?

Comment: @musicamante my aim is to avoid the processing - if unnecessary keys are pressed. , self.first_option value is  changed by pressing right or left arrow keys

Comment: As said, the above check already covers the issue, as it will only process the listed keys, *any* other key (*including* the shortcuts) that is not part of that list will *not* be processed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want to process specific keys, then you either check if the event key is in the list of "handled" keys and proceed with its processing, or just *ignore* the event if it's not.

Note that you must *not* compare the string representation of the key, but its QKeySequence instead.

```py
class Dynamic_Widgets(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        # ...
        self.item_list_sc.append(QKeySequence(self.lbl_1_sc.text()))
        self.item_list_sc.append(QKeySequence(self.lbl_2_sc.text()))
        self.item_list_sc.append(QKeySequence(self.lbl_3_sc.text()))

        self.key_indexes = {}
        for i, key in enumerate(self.item_list_sc):
            shortcut = self.store_sc[i] = QShortcut(key, self)
            shortcut.activated.connect(self.result)
            self.key_indexes[key] = i

    def result(self):
        shortcut = self.sender()
        sc_key_index = self.key_indexes.get(shortcut.key())
        if sc_key_index is None:
            return
        self.first_option = sc_key_index
        self.first_option_result = self.item_list[sc_key_index]
        self.func_final_result()

    def keyPressEvent(self, event):
        key = event.key()
        if key not in (Qt.Key_Return, Qt.Key_Enter, Qt.Key_Left, Qt.Key_Right):
            return
        if self.active_part == 1:
            if key in (Qt.Key_Return, Qt.Key_Enter):
                self.first_option = 0
            elif (key == Qt.Key_Right 
                and self.first_option < len(self.item_list) - 1):
                    self.first_option += 1
            elif key == Qt.Key_Left and self.first_option > 0:
                self.first_option -= 1

            if self.first_option >= 0:
                self.first_option_result = self.item_list[self.first_option]
                self.func_final_result()
```

Alternatively, use an `if/elif/else` block that always check **only** for the key, and eventually process the key according to the other conditions, otherwise `return` since no key match has been found to that point:

```py
    def keyPressEvent(self, event):
        if self.active_part == 1:
            key = event.key()
            if key in (Qt.Key_Return, Qt.Key_Enter):
                self.first_option = 0
            elif key == Qt.Key_Right:
                if self.first_option < len(self.item_list) - 1:
                    self.first_option += 1
            elif key == Qt.Key_Left:
                if self.first_option > 0:
                    self.first_option -= 1
            else:
                return

            if self.first_option >= 0:
                self.first_option_result = self.item_list[self.first_option]
                self.func_final_result()
```

<sup>Note: for such situations, you must *always* use a QGridLayout, otherwise items might become not properly aligned under certain circumstances; eventually, consider QFormLayout. Also, avoid putting multiple function calls in a single line, there is absolutely no benefit in that, and it only makes your code cumbersome and difficult to read (and, thus, to debug).</sup>

Comment: Got your Idea. Thanks, How to change the background colour of the selected item. Now I try the following in function func_final_result(),  self.style().unpolish(self.lbl_item['lbl101'])
        self.lbl_item['lbl101'].setStyleSheet("background-color: blue")
        self.lbl_item['lbl101'].ensurePolished().  But nothing will change

Comment: @tckraomuqnt I don't know what `self.lbl_item` is and what does it contain, so I cannot answer your question (besides, it's off topic). In any case, if you want to set a specific stylesheet for the *selected* label, first of all you have to ensure that any previous label gets its stylesheet reset. Calling `unpolish()` or `ensurePolished()` are normally unnecessary whenever you overwrite a stylesheet.